# Reputation with letter `k`

Tags: support, reputation

The letter `k` represents 1000.

234 is displayed as just `234`
2345 is `2345` even though it is in the thousands and
23456 is `23k`

When is reputation displayed with the letter `k`?

Comment: I assume `234 is displayed as just 123` is a typo?

Comment: It's easy to conclude that for reputation < 10000, there's no K.

Comment: @maroun-maroun I'd accept that answer

Comment: I'm not sure what's so bad about this question. Determining when the site decides to use the shorthand for "thousand" is a decent enough question since it happens in different contexts...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It really depends on where you look. In the top bar, and in the community dropdown menu, there is never a 'k'. In my [network profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=profile), it shows the 'k' already above 1000:

[image]

---

In the side menu of the iOS app, the cut-off seems to be 10k:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I found two more examples where the cut-off is 10k: on pages with a list of questions

[image]

---

and the question detail page:

[image]